# Restoring files from the recycle bin in python

Tags: python, recycle-bin

Is there any to restore files from the recycle bin in python?

Here's the code:

```
from send2trash import send2trash

file_name = "test.txt"

operation = input("Enter the operation to perform[delete/restore]: ")

if operation == "delete":
    send2trash(file_name)
    print(f"Successfully deleted {file_name}")

else:
    # Code to restore the file from recycle bin.
    pass
```

Here when I type `"restore"` in the `input()` function, I want to restore my deleted file from the recycle bin.

Is there any way to achieve this in python?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

EDIT:

Thanks for the answer @Kenivia, but I am facing one small issue:

```
import winshell

r = list(winshell.recycle_bin())  # this lists the original path of all the all items in the recycling bin
file_name = "C:\\test\\Untitled_1.txt" # This file is located in the recycle bin

index = r.index(file_name) # to determine the index of your file

winshell.undelete(r[index].original_filename())
```

When I run this code, I get an error: `ValueError: 'C:\\test\\Untitled_1.txt' is not in list`. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would depend on your operating system.

**Linux**

it's as simple as moving it from the trash folder to the original path. The location of the trash folder differs from distro to distro, but this is where it typically is.

There is a [command line tool](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) that you can use, or dig through the code to get some ideas.

```
import subprocess as sp # here subprocess is just used to run the command, you can also use os.system but that is discouraged

sp.run(['mv','/home/USERNAME/.local/share/Trash/files/test.txt', '/ORIGINAL/PATH/')
```

**macOS**

On macOS, you do the same thing as you do in Linux, except the trash path is `~/.Trash`

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.run(['mv','~/.Trash/test.txt', '/ORIGINAL/PATH/')
```

Note that macOS stores information about the files at `~/.Trash/.DS_Store`, where Linux stores them at `/home/USERNAME/.local/share/Trash/info/`. This can be useful if you don't know the original path of the files.

**Windows**

you have to use `winshell`. See [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-access-recycle-bin-in-python-192a685e31fb) for more details

```
import winshell 

r = list(winshell.recycle_bin())  # this lists the original path of all the all items in the recycling bin
index = r.index("C:\ORIGINAL\PATH\test.txt") # to determine the index of your file

winshell.undelete(r[index].original_filename())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but when I use `r.index(file)`, python gives me an error `ValueError: 'file' is not in list`, though the path of the file I have given is right. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You might have used `r.index("file")` instead of `r.index(file)`, if not, please print the list `r` and look for the path of your text file.

Comment: I tried printing the list, and the file path in the list seems to be the same as path I have given.

Comment: the fact that the error message mentions `'file'` means that you put in a string - `"file"` instead of a variable called `file`. Can you just double check that you passed the right thing into `r.index()`?

Comment: Can you please show me your entire code, either by editing the question or sending it in a comment?

Comment: I used something like `index = r.index(x)`, where x is a variable that stores the path of the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229969/discussion-between-kenivia-and-lenovo-360).

Comment: @Kevinia: Hey, I know I'm late, but I think I have figured out the problem (Windows). The reason why `r.index(file)` doesn't work is each item in `r` is an instance of `ShellRecycledItem()`, while `file` is just a string. The `ShellRecycledItem()` class has a method called `original_filename()` which we can use to get the actual name of the file. So, instead of `r = list(winshell.recycle_bin())`, we can do something like `r = [name.original_filename() for name in list(winshell.recycle_bin())]` to make `r.index(file)` work. Thank you so much for your help! Upvoted + Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Colab** (you are the `root` user)

Import the shell utility for Python:

```py
import shutil
```

Move the file from trash to a selected destination:

```py
shutil.move('/root/.local/share/Trash/files/<deleted-file>', '<destination-path>')
```